# When i use texture paint, it doesn't show when i render it

Tags: texture-painting

So, I have UV unwrapped my model and made a texture for it and then started texturing the model, at first it appears textured when I render the image, but for some random reason after when I paint something it doesn't show anymore when I render it. Does anyone know why this is the case? [image]

So this is something random,

[image]

And this is it rendered, as you can see the thing I drew isn't on the model. The thing is it worked before I saved the texture in a texture folder. This really confuses me since it used to work on this exact model, anyone knows why?

Comment: Make sure you're saving the texture you painted on before rendering

Comment: @MrZak yeah, it worked. Now I feel stupid. Thanks anyways